# OnClick Not Firing?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm new to android and having trouble getting some simple things going!

Here is some basic code:

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Lets go ahead and set our buttons up.
    ServerButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.ServerButton);
    ClientButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.ClientButton);
    BTServer = new BluetoothServerService(this, mHandler);      
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
    public void ServerButtonClick(View v){
    Log.d("BLUETOOTH MAIN ACTIVITY", "It got here");
    BTServer.start();
}

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        switch (msg.what){
        case HANDLER_CHANGE_SERVER_STATUS:
            switch(msg.arg1){
            case SERVER_STATUS_OFF:
                CURRENT_SERVER_STATUS = SERVER_STATUS_OFF;
                //We should probably add some logging, and the change to the button
                break;
            case SERVER_STATUS_ON:
                CURRENT_SERVER_STATUS = SERVER_STATUS_ON;
                //Again lets add some logging, etc.
                break;
            case SERVER_STATUS_ON_CONNECTED:
                CURRENT_SERVER_STATUS = SERVER_STATUS_ON_CONNECTED;
                //Again lets add some logging, etc.
                break;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
};
```

My XML Looks like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ServerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="146dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:text="Connect to Server" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ClientButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Start Server" 
    android:onClick="ServerButtonClick"/>
```

In my logs, I see the logs saying it creates the BTServer object, but I can't get any logs to show up when I click the button.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: u mean u r not getting onclick event on ClientButton ?

Comment: where is the button click method......

Comment: Isn't the Button Click Method specified in the XML?  android:onClick="ServerButtonClick"/>

That should mean on click it runs public void ServerButtonClick(View v){
    Log.d("BLUETOOTH MAIN ACTIVITY", "It got here");
    BTServer.start();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a click action for **ClientButton** inside `onCreate` method

```
 ClientButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
```

also for **ServerButton** define a click action like the above as

```
 ServerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // Perform action on click
                 }
             });
```

Comment: So you think I should set it in code instead of XML? I just tried this and it worked, so I will use this method from now on. Any clue why it didn't work from the XML file?

Comment: you have to define the click event in java code, XML can't trigger any action event

Comment: Ohhh...Makes so much more sense now! I appreciate everyone's help. I'm sure you will see many more questions come up from me soon!

Answer (score 1):

For me, I find it's best to have your Activity implement android.view.View.OnClickListener, then set your Button's onClickListener to your Activity.

Here's an example Activity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Home extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

        Button serverButton = (Button)this.findViewById (R.id.ServerButton);
        serverButton.setOnClickListener (this);

        Button clientButton = (Button)this.findViewById (R.id.ClientButton);
        clientButton.setOnClickListener (this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View button)
    {
        int buttonId = button.getId ();

        if (buttonId == R.id.ServerButton)
        {
            // Do server stuff.
        }

        if (buttonId == R.id.ClientButton)
        {
            // Do client stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android when you define the android:onClick="someMethod" attribute it only implements the OnClickListener for you.

So it is your responsibility to define the onCLickListener Method and call your ServerButtonClick method from that.

Add this method in your Activity OnCreate Method. It would work.

```
ServerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
            ServerButtonClick();  
          }
       });
```

Also, **android:onClick method works only if API level > 4 onwards. so if you're targeting Minimum SDK version < 1.6 please do not use it**